# Reverse ssh tunnel: connexion refused

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunnel

I'm trying to setup a reverse ssh tunnel as follows:

```
A ==========> B <----X---- C
```

I'm initiating the tunnel from `A` with:

```
ssh -p 443 -NR 19001:localhost:21 userOnB@B
```

On computer `B` I can use the tunnel fine if I use:

```
ssh -p 19001 userOnA@localhost
```

But if I'm connecting to `B` with its name, IP address or another computer (say `C`) I get a `ssh: connect to host port 19001: Connection refused`.

What is wrong?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

By default tunnel endpoints only listen on 127.0.0.1, so they can't be accessed from other machines. To change this you first need to add this to `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` on the server:

```
GatewayPorts clientspecified
```

and then when establishing the tunnel specify the listen address as 0.0.0.0:

```
ssh -p 443 -NR 0.0.0.0:19001:localhost:21 userOnB@B
```

Comment: on ubuntu you might need ```sudo reload sshd```

Comment: It's so annoying that serverfault and stackoverflow are separate, because the contents overlap so often. I specifically joined serverfault to upvote this. Great answer!

Comment: `systemctl reload sshd` for the `systemd` users these days. Also, it's my fault for not reading correctly, but the word "server" doesn't really mean much to me when both computers are considered servers. The `sshd` configuration must be done on the *middleman* server, the one the reverse ssh tunnel is dialing.

Comment: This is a great solution! It helps me!